# Same code not working in PyCharm but working outside PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, or-tools

I am trying to run a google ortools example in PyCharm and got the following errors:

```
/Users/edamame/project/ortools/simple_program.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edamame/project/ortools/simple_program.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ortools.linear_solver'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, if I run the same code outside the PyCharm (under the corresponding project venv), it works fine:

```
(venv) edamame$ pwd
/Users/edamame/project/ortools/
(venv) edamame$ python simple_program.py 
Solution:
Objective value =  4.0
x =  1.0
y =  1.0
```

I then tried to print below in both cases:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

The outputs:

In PyCharm:

```
/Users/edamame/project/venv/bin/python
/Users/edamame/project/ortools/so_example.py
/Users/edamame/project/ortools
/Users/edamame/project
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Users/edamame/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/edamame/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg
/Users/edamame/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-10.0.1-py3.6.egg
```

Outside PyCharm:

```
(venv) edamame$ python so_example.py 
/Users/edamame/project/ortools
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Users/edamame/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/edamame/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg
/Users/edamame/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-10.0.1-py3.6.egg
```

They seem to be the same though ... not sure what could be the problem ...

How do I make the same code working in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a namespace collision between custom `ortools` package and the installed one. PyCharm adds the project root (`/Users/edamame/project`) to `PYTHONPATH` by default and it causes the problem.

Either rename your custom `ortools` package or disable **Add content roots to PYTHONPATH** option in the dedicated Run Configuration in PYCharm.

Answer (score 1):

The env var PYTHONPATH is relevant. In both situations, print the value of `sys.path`:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

In bash, you may find it helpful to enter the venv and then `$ open /Applications/PyCharm.app` (or whatever it's called on your Mac). Then the running pycharm will inherit PYTHONPATH from bash.

Here is another approach. Within pycharm type CMD-, (command comma) for preferences, search for Project Structure, right click on the edamame/project folder, and choose alt-S Sources. This will add the folder to your path within pycharm. Again, use `print()` to verify `sys.path` contains what you expect it to contain.

Comment: I print the sys.path for both cases. It is long, so I added to the original questions.

Comment: I hadn't realized you were following the https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/python/mac instructions. To adapt them to pycharm, try clicking CMD-comma and Add an Existing environment Project Interpreter which matches the bash output of `which python`. That is the usual way to copy a conda or pip venv into a Pycharm or Idea environment.